# splitting a dataframe into several smaller datframes with an equal number of columns

Tags: r, split, multiple-columns

If I have a dataframe in R:

> dim(df)
> [1]      9 705936

and I want to divide it into 28 parts by splitting it on the columns, and still have all nine rows when I am finished in each smaller dataframe. How do I do that? Because I have managed to screw this up every which way that I've tried and I'm all out of patience. It seems like this should be a one line command but I can't get it.

Comment: Could you add a sample of your data and what has failed?

Comment: You have a data fame of ~706k columns! Consider long format. Even Hadley recommends [long form](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#longer)!

Comment: Think modulo into a list? dim2 <- 1:705936;  index your ends, which(dim2 %% 25212 == 0),  then you're just using that info to `[`.

Answer (score 5):

**Update II** after testing with fake dataframe with 705936 columns (removed previous answer):

**The correct answer is using `split.default`**

```
split.default(df, rep(1:28, each = 25212))
```

Comment: I think your 28 wants to be 25212 in `1:(ncol(df)/28`, else there are 25212 results, `length(lapply(1:(length(dim2_lst)/28), function(x) dim2_lst[c(28 * x -1, 28 * x)]))
[1] 25212`, at least as to the desired split results. Here I've just applied to one dim, 1:705936, wrapped in a list for lapply, because I work in tiny RAM.

Comment: Thank you TarJae! This is exactly what I needed! To the people commenting on its size,  I know the data frame is unwieldy  with with 705936 columns. Its just a temporary object I intend to delete immediately after extracting what I need from it, which thankfully I now can. Once again, thank you TarJae!